# How to override mail action of site invitation email in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

Currently I am using alfresco 3.4d community version. I want to change site invitation email template as currently its not supporting HTML tag.

I want to use HTML tag in `.ftl` file for site invitation email.

**Is there any way to achieve the same?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Alch3mi5t:Alfresco 3.4d does not supports html content inside mail.

Follow below links for this.

http://krutikjayswal.blogspot.in/2015/07/html-mail-action-in-alfresco34d.html

http://krutikjayswal.blogspot.in/2015/07/html-mail-content-inside-site.html

Answer (score 0):

So,

first of all, `.ftl` IS a `HTML` based language.
You must use an `.ftl` file and you can put your custom `HTML` code.

The path you want to check in Alfresco is:

`Company Home > Data Dictionary> Email Templates>`

There are a bunch of folders, I guess you want templates inside the folder `invite`.

In there you'll find all the Freemarker templates used by Alfresco for email notifications (there are different files in it as they're used dynamically for internationalization purposes and for different kind of notifications). The one that you're asking for is `invite-email.html.ftl`. Just copy it in the same folder, rename it (eg. `invite-email.html.ftl.backup`), and do apply your changes.

You'll also find a `notify_user_email.ftl.sample` inside the `Notify Email Templates` that you can use for testing if you want to see how the notification email looks (just rename it to `notify_user_email.ftl` and rename the original to something else, eg. `notify_user_email.ftl.backup`). Mind by default the notification email will be send overnight so maybe not the best one to test :)

That should help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help but using this I am not able to send email with HTML format.

Comment: Excuse me but here: `http://pastie.org/10276946` is the extract of my Alfresco instance Email Invite template file. The file is named `invite-email.html.ftl` how can you not see the HTML code in it? It's the HTML format you're just allowed to use Freemarker markdown for variables usage that Alfresco gives you, and you just need to rename the file from HTML to html.ftl. Editing last part: you're asking to use HTML tag in the ftl email invite template? Look at the link pasted here, and you'll see the ftl already support the HTML tag natively (or please rephrase your question).